# Syncfusion Chart in Flutter

Tags: flutter, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

When using the CandleSeries chart, the zoom in/out functions works fine, however, the intervals on axis can be not ideal to view the graph when zoomed in.

See the image below.

[image: download]

On TradingView, there is an ability to change the axis interval while scrolling the mouse on the axis column, thus making the data bit more readable.

Is there a way to achieve something like this within the flutter package?

Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 1):

We have analyzed your query. You can achieve your requirement by setting the [enableAutoIntervalOnZooming](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/ChartAxis/enableAutoIntervalOnZooming.html) property to false in the [DateTimeAxis](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/DateTimeAxis-class.html). By default, [enableAutoIntervalOnZooming](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/ChartAxis/enableAutoIntervalOnZooming.html) is set to true, so the axis intervals will change while scrolling. We have shared a code snippet for your reference. Please let us know if you need any further assistance.

**Code Snippet:**

```
   zoomPanBehavior: ZoomPanBehavior(
          enablePanning: true,
          zoomMode: ZoomMode.x,
          enableMouseWheelZooming: true,
        ),
        primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(
          enableAutoIntervalOnZooming: false,
        ),
```